# My dachshund turnt into a golden retriever?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendogs-and-cats

On another website I am posting pictures of nintendogs + cats and someone said my dachshund [my dachund where it was a gold retriever](https://i.quotev.com/img/q/u/18/11/13/pj2ohwmfdr.jpg)

I asked them and showed them a picture of a golden retriever from the game but they said judging from the snout it looked like a golden retriever

So I went here to ask if there is something wrong with my game becouse the info says she is a dachund but she looks like a golden retriever 
Is this a little graphic or a model glitch or is it a lot worse

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, your Nintendogs(&Cats) Dachshund is indeed a Dachshund.

Looking up some wiki articles on the game's [Dachshunds](http://nintendogs.wikia.com/wiki/Miniature_Dachshund) and [Golden Retrievers](http://nintendogs.wikia.com/wiki/Golden_Retriever), your's is *definitely not a retriever*. It looks to be a Red, Yellow, or Golden coloured Dachshund. For some more direct comparrisons:
[image: Comparrison picture of 6 dogs]

1. Your Dachshund
2. A real Dachshund with similar fur colour to yours
3. Another Nintendogs&Cats Dachshund (black & tan fur)
4. A Golden Retriever
5. A real Golden Retriever
6. Another Nintendogs&Cats Golden Retriever.

It is a little difficult to determine based on the snout - the model the game uses for the Dachshunds is a little less pronounced than some real life ones posses, but it is additionally difficult based on the angle of the screenshot you provided. Still, yours does look like the snout of the real life Dachshund.

The ears of your dog more closely match that of a Dachshound. While on the bottom row we can see that both the virtual and real Golden Retrievers have similarly shorter ears that do not match the shape of your dog's.

The legs may also be a key identifying feature; those of your dog appear slightly shorter than those of the retrievers on the bottom row. Again, however, it is a bit difficult to tell leg lengths based on the angle of the screenshot provided.